# D: How to use binding to C++ lib with D?

Tags: c++, binding, d, gdal, dub

I found very needed for my binding to lib named GDAL.
https://github.com/craig-dillabaugh/gdal

The problem that there is no examples of it's usage. Before I have never used any bindings.

dub.json include next string:
`"libs" : ["gdal"]`

So it seems that it need lib file with this name.

In the old [commits](https://github.com/craig-dillabaugh/gdal/commit/5b43536f9180cba5efb895666d3cfd8d45c85e03) I found example of compilation without dub: `dmd test_gdal_d.d gdal.d -L-ldgal`

Original gdal distrib do not include lib with such name. There is only `gdal111.dll` lib.
So I converted it with `implib` to `gdal111.lib`. With command `implib /s gdal111.lib gdal111.dll`

From 11MB lib become 1MB of size.

With Dependency Walker I looked it table of symbols. It's have symbols like `GDALGetRasterXSize`
I am trying to build all with next command:

`dmd D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master\source\App.d D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master\source\gdal.d -L -Igdal111.lib`

but I am getting next error:

`D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master>dmd D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master\source\App.d D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master\source\gdal.d -L -Igdal111.lib
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.17
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2013  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALClose
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALGetRasterCount
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALGetRasterXSize
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALGetRasterYSize
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALOpen
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALAllRegister
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALIdentifyDriver
App.obj(App)
 Error 42: Symbol Undefined _GDALCreate
--- errorlevel 8`

I put archive with all stuff here http://dlang.ru/gdal-d-binding.zip

**UPD:** I got GDAL run!!!

I gist add string:
`pragma( lib, "libgdal.lib" );` at example, and it's run. Soon I hope to push some code to github.

Comment: Try to generate the __*.di__ interface with [*implib*](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/implib.html).  It's also possible that the example was made for the static library file (__*.lib__).

Comment: implib will make the .lib, not the .di. But these errors are about a missing .lib so it is what you should try. implib can be downloaded here http://ftp.digitalmars.com/bup.zip and you just run it on the dll. probably `implib /s ldgal.lib ldgal.dll`

Comment: I tried. But without result...

Comment: Nothing happened or did you still get the same error? Be sure you pass the generated .lib file to the compiler too when building.

Comment: I am trying to compile it with next command:
``dmd D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master\source\App.d D:\code\binding\gdal-master\gdal-master\source\gdal.d -L -Ilibgdal.lib``

The error is same. But I am not sure that command is correct. Lib name is libgdal. And I linking with it with -L -Ilibgdal.lib

Comment: The -I is wrong. Just add the `libgdal.lib` to the end of the command with no esxtra stuff around it. Like: `dmd path\to\App.d path\to\gdal.d libgdal.lib`

Answer (score 2):

writing up the solution we got together from the comments here:

First, you need to make the lib file. `implib` can be downloaded here ftp.digitalmars.com/bup.zip and you just run it on the dll, `implib /s ldgal.lib ldgal.dll` to generate the import library.

Once that is made, you need to add it to the build. There's two ways to do that: add `ldgal.lib` to the end of the command line to dmd (without any other switches, just add the file, dmd will see that it is a .lib and do the right thing) or add `pragma(lib, "ldgal");` to your main source file.